# Preserve pandas display format after cell coloring

Tags: python, pandas

How do I preserve the percentage format after coloring the cells?

```
import pandas as pd

sample_tab = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-0.1, 0.2],
                           'b': [0, 0.5]})

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}%'.format

sample_tab.style.apply(lambda x: ["background: red" if v < 0 else "background: green" if v > 0 else "" for v in x], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.format(":.n"%)` after applying `apply` function.

```
sample_tab = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-0.132, 0.234], 'b': [0, 0.534]})
sample_tab.style.apply(lambda x: ["background: red" if v < 0 else "background: green" if v > 0 else "" for v in x], axis = 1).format("{:.2}%")
```

[image]

```
sample_tab.style.apply(lambda x: ["background: red" if v < 0 else "background: green" if v > 0 else "" for v in x], axis = 1).format("{:.3}%")
```

[image]